# Can someone help fix the non-scrolling scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the slimScroll scrollbar plugin, but I had to modify it. I am trying to make it so that you pass the plugin the div that needs scrolling and using the same space as that (in the parent) the scrollbar appears. I have gotten it to add the scrollbar where i want in the dom, but it isnt scrolling. I dont know why. Can anyone help?

Code is here for you to play with/correct.

http://jsfiddle.net/rgmrw/5/

Thanks!

EDIT: The solution should also not add any divs/wrap existing ones. (Doing so messes up other existing javascript code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot `$(el).scrollTop()` an element that isnt cutting off its children elements, even if a parent is.

Basic Concept Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DY9CT/
Plugin Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rgmrw/11/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I fixed it;

I actually didn't do anything, I was messing around in code but couldn't get it to work properly, so i copy pasted the code again from the original plugin at http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll and it worked out of the box :)

http://jsfiddle.net/rgmrw/9/

Comment: the problem with that is that it scrolls the top bar, which was the whole purpose of the modification

Comment: so you want the top bar to stay in place, and the rest scrollable ?

Comment: If that's what you want just make the top bar position:fixed;

Comment: ok, it should work now, @Jamie: no, you should get the scrollbar going only on the simpletest div. this way you can get multiple items on you website scrollable instead of the whole page.

Comment: If all you want is a different div to scroll - why are you using a huge plugin? You could achieve the same thing with <div><h3>Title bar</h3><div class="scroll">content to scroll</div></div> and just make div.scroll {overflow-y:auto;height:200px;} - overflow property and a fixed height, no javascript necesarry

Comment: I guess I didnt write the whole thing. I also modified it so that it doesnt add any divs. I do this because it messes up javascript code.

Comment: @Jamie I like the styling of the plugin. It fades away when the mouse isnt over the div, and looks much nicer than the built in scrollbar (yes i know you can 'hide' the built in scroll bar, but its hideous to be blunt).

Comment: No worries - it's just a lot of code to achieve a really simple affect that's all dude. If you like the plugin that's cool!

Comment: Ok, but then something went wrong with your rewrite, start from the working version and modify it peace by peace while testing if it stays working

Comment: well, the thing is that in order to get rid of the code where it wraps the given selector, i have to do many changes, one isnt enough